# Best way to find average query time for critical queries in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, prometheus, percona

We have percona monitoring tool for monitoring Mysql db, generating slow log file report not gives us instant results. do we have any best approach to handle it using metrics/ promql's or query analytics etc. where we get min,max,average time of critical queries

Comment: In which programming language your application executes the MySQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

min,max,average -- These don't make sense until you have enough samples to take min,max,average against.  Rethink the need for "instant results".

`pt-query-digest` could be run daily or hourly (or whatever) to get results for the "recent past".

A lot of metrics can be graphed by the various monitoring tools available from Percona, MariaDB, and Oracle, plus others.  Some cost money.  Some come "close" to "instant results" even for slow queries.

Please describe your goal in different words; we may be able to better direct you.

Metrics like `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';` (or a graph monitoring that) can spot a spike in realtime.  But it there is nothing actionable in knowing that there is a spike.

I prefer looking at the slowlog afterward.  The "worst" queries are readily identified by `pt-query-digest`.  Spikes and bottlenecks can be identified, but not until they are "finished".

Deadlocks come from the hard-to-parse `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS;`, but only one at a time and after the fact.

In a not-well-tuned system, the *first* entry in pt-query-digest is (sometimes) a query that consumes over 50% of the system resources.  Fixing that *one* query makes a big difference.  Very cost-effective.